# Find by highest field value and ignore anything lower in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following table setup:
[image]

Running the query in Mongoose as follows:

```
leaguepositions.find({leagueID:leagueID}).populate('team_id').sort({position: 1}).execAsync();
```

I'd like to be able to return only the results from the highest value of `week`. Right now the highest is `2`, if that value was `100` then I'd like to ignore the other 99 weeks and only display the highest value?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all the entry only from highest week ?

Comment: Exactly. Esensically ({leagueID:leagueId, week: 2})

Comment: Are you okay with having 2 query ? I don't think it can we done in one query. There is a open JIRA issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377

Comment: I had originally used 2 queries... :( Good to know there is a ticket for it. Although I doubt it'll get made any time soon being 2 years old :)